# PyWPS installation won't see cpl_port.h

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, pywps

I'm trying to install PyWPS on my computer and when I run

```
 sudo python setup.py install
```

I'm receiving : 
"extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:2853:22: fatal error: cpl_port.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1"

I've Gdal 2.1.2 installed on my computer and I can see the cpl_port header in /usr/include/gdal/.

Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: PyWPS is not dependent on GDAL. What version are you trying to install? Could you please add to your question the contents of the `requirements.txt` file in the root PyWPS folder?

Comment: I was trying to install 3.2.5. I've opened the requirement and it says 
"GDAL==1.10.0
lxml==3.5.0"
That might be the reason I can't install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have GDAL installed you can try to skip it. Open the `requirements.txt` file and comment out the respective line; it should look like this:

```
#GDAL==1.10.0
lxml==3.5.0
```

The run again `sudo python setup.py install`.

Note that this only applies to releases 3.2.X.